# Let $f,g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that $A=\{x \in X:f(x) \geq g(x)\}$ is closed without using $\epsilon$-balls.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $f,g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Let $A = \{x \in X:f(x) \geq g(x)\}$. Can I show that $A$ is closed without using any form of $\epsilon$-balls? I was able to do this pretty easily using $\epsilon$-balls and the definition for sequence convergence. My professor hinted that I should solve this problem using only the topological properties of $X$, but how is that even possible?

For an overview of my proof, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A$ where $x_n \rightarrow x \in X$. Assume $f(x)<g(x)$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_n)<g(x_n)$ for $n \geq N$. This is a contradiction since $f(x_n) \geq g(x_n)$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore $f(x) \geq g(x) \implies x \in A \implies A$ is closed.

How can this be accomplished without using an $\epsilon-N$ definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(f,g):X\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous and $(z,y)\mapsto z-y$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Accordingly, $h(x):= f(x)-g(x)$ is continuous on $X$ and $A=h^{-1}([0,\infty))$ which must be closed, being the pre-image of a closed set under a continuous map.

Comment: Wow. That is a lot simpler than the epsilon proof. Thanks.